# Node.js fs module not found in Pushkin installation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have installed Pushkin on my Mac as directed [here](https://pushkin-social-science-at-scale.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/gettingstarted.html). I have gotten to the point where I navigate to the site at http://localhost, but I get an error from the browser with the following stack trace:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: _fs.default.readFileSync is not a function
> at Object../node_modules/pushkinComponent9afd1966f4b248feb0fc0f32c453fb3a/build/index.js (index.js:46)
>    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
>   at fn (bootstrap:150)
>   at Module../src/experiments.js (experiments.js:1)
>   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
>   at fn (bootstrap:150)
>   at Module../src/components/QuizTile/TakeQuiz.js (Header.js:104)
>   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
>   at fn (bootstrap:150)
>    at Module../src/App.js (App.css?498e:37)
>   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
>   at fn (bootstrap:150)
>   at Module../src/index.js (index.css?e32c:37)
>   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
>   at fn (bootstrap:150)
>   at Object.1 (session.js:9)
>   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
>   at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
>   at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
>   at main.chunk.js:1
```

Looking at index.js, line 20 sets _fs and requires the fs module:

```
var _fs = _interopRequireDefault(require("fs"));
```

However, according to [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs), the fs module no longer exists. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you try rmoving 'fs' from the package.json of your front-end and see what happens?

Comment: OK, it's more complicated of a problem than I thought. It's definitely a bug in pushkin, and not one I can quickly solve. I'll post back here when we've got it figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Pushkin (specifically in the [basic experiment template](https://github.com/pushkin-consortium/pushkin-exptemplates-basic)) that has now been squashed. It's actually something of a mystery as to why it ever worked.

Fixing this bug required tracking down a lot of relatively obscure facts about Node and React, so I'm documenting below in case it helps anyone else.

Here is what was probably going on. Apparently, although 'fs' is native to Node, it is incompatible with create-react-app, which is the scaffold for the Pushkin front end. Interestingly, the Pushkin front end does not actually use 'fs'. Rather, 'fs' is used by an individual experiment to read its config file.

I fixed this using [babel-plugin-static-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-static-fs). At build time, this plugin actually reads the content of whatever file you wanted to read and writes it directly into the built javascript.

The downside of babel plugins is that you can't use them with create-react-app. (Rather, the whole point of create-react-app is that it manages your babel and webpack configurations for you ... which means you can't customize by adding an additional one that you'd like to use.) HOWEVER, individual Pushkin experiments are built independently of the website front-end (the thing that uses create-react-app) and are then loaded as npm modules. So adding the static-fs plugin to the experiment template fixes the problem.

Comment: I have followed these steps so far, including [wiping docker](https://nam01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F44785585%2Fhow-to-delete-all-docker-local-docker-images&data=02%7C01%7Cn00612546%40unf.edu%7C326d10f78319480cd43f08d7d1ee4fea%7Cdf29b2fa8929482f9dbb60ff4df224c4%7C1%7C0%7C637208693794516004&sdata=keOy7TTYxzdyl%2Btr2qfokgkCbKBf5FXnErDl1wdnIFs%3D&reserved=0), but now I'm getting other issues before I even get this far. I'll post another question because it's an entirely different issue. I'll post the link once I have it.

Comment: I have found that this does in fact fix the issue I was having, and doesn't seem to be related to the other problem. Accepted.